# How to get the subdomain value from a url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how can I get the subdomain value in rails, is there a built-in way to do this?

e.g.

```
test123.example.com
```

I want the test123 part of the url.

Comment: you mind using a regular expression?

Comment: I think this would be better answered by providing a solution to find the subdomain of a string as well as the current url.  Considering this is the #1 result on google for the search "rails get the subdomain of a url"

Answer (score 31):

Rails 3.0 has this capability built-in, you can access the subdomain from `request.subdomain`.

You can also route based on the subdomain:

```
class SupportSubdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain == "support"
  end
end

Basecamp::Application.routes do
  constraints(SupportSubdomain) do
    match "/foo/bar", :to => "foo#bar"
  end
end
```

If you're using 2.3, you'll need to use a plugin such as [subdomain-fu](https://github.com/intridea/subdomain-fu/tree/v0.5.4).

Comment: Is there a way to do this when using Rack Middleware?  request.subdomain is not available only request.host

Comment: @cman77 You could try something like [this](http://tannerburson.com/2009/01/extracting-subdomains-in-sinatra.html/), or [rack-subdomain](https://github.com/mattt/rack-subdomain) for more complex situations.

Comment: @CyleHunter sure, if you're using something like [pow](http://pow.cx) to do development name-resolution.

Answer (score 13):

Use the following method inside your controller

```
request.subdomains
```

This Returns an array of subdomains

Comment: `request.subdomain` does not return an array. `request.subdomains` does. Note the plural form of subdomain.

Answer (score 8):

In case you are working with a string, and assuming it can be a true URI, you can do this to extract the subdomain.

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://test123.example.com')
uri.host.split('.').first
=> "test123"
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13243810/3407381

Comment: Gave a -1 since Rails has a built in function that does this already, so this would reinvent the wheel and might be more prone to errors.

Comment: +1 because I actually needed to parse a string. I was trying to parse `request.referrer`. Don't listen to @corvuszero. The question wasn't specific. Thanks!

Comment: I gave a +1 since you don't always have a request to work with

Comment: this will fail for TLDs that contain a period, such as `mysite.co.uk` for example.

Answer (score 7):

[account_location](https://github.com/rails/account_location) is also a good plugin. After using it, you can find the account based on different subdomains. And you can find out subdomain from url just by writing

```
request.subdomains(0).first
```

in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Simple in your controller just do the following

```
unless request.subdomains.any?
   #No domains available redirect
   redirect_to subdomain: 'www'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SubdomainFu plugin](https://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu). This plugin gives you a method current_subdomain which returns the current_subdomain of your app.

You can also have a look at [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains)

**UPDATE**

You can also use `request.subdomains` this will give you an array of subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking to get the subdomains on localhost using WEBrick:

Put `config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 0` into `config/environments/development.rb` and everything should work.

Link to SO post here:
[Can I make Rails / WEBrick recognize entries in /etc/hosts as subdomains (instead of domains)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388948/can-i-make-rails-webrick-recognize-entries-in-etc-hosts-as-subdomains-instea/31062044#31062044)

Link to Github post:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12438

Comment: That is indeed a nice little gotcha there! Glad you mentioned this

Answer (score 1):

current domain with subdomains:

```rb
"#{request.subdomain}.#{request.domain}"
# or
"#{request.subdomains.join(".")}.#{request.domain}"
```

Comment: Conscious this would prepend a `.` if there's no subdomain; a more robust approach (if subdomain may be blank) is something like `current_domain = (request.subdomains + [request.domain]).join('.')`

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but here's what I used in older versions of rails.

`subdomain = request.subdomains.join('.')`

It should be backwards compatible in newer versions

Answer (score 0):

Recently worked on similar task - but the goal were to remove the subdomain from URL, ignoring the `www` and any combination of `.co.uk` or other top level domain. Maybe someone will find it useful:

```rb
def self.remove_subdomain_from_url(url)
  root_domain = 'example'

  uri = URI.parse(url)
  host = uri.host.sub(/^www\./, '')

  root_domain_index = host.split('.').find_index { |host_element| host_element.include?(root_domain) }

  return url if root_domain_index.zero?

  new_host = []
  new_host.push('www') if url.include?('www')
  new_host.concat(host.split('.')[root_domain_index..-1])

  uri.host = new_host.join('.')
  uri.to_s
end
```

And a bunch of tests that might help you to understand the code:

```rb
it 'does not remove www from url' do
  expect(remove_subdomain_from_url('https://www.pl.example.com/path/?originalSubdomain=pl')).to eq(
    "https://www.example.com/path/?originalSubdomain=de"
  )
end

it 'removes subdomain from url' do
  expect(remove_subdomain_from_url('https://www.de.example.com/path/?originalSubdomain=de')).to eq(
    "https://www.example.com/path/?originalSubdomain=de"
  )
end

it 'works properly with http' do
  expect(remove_subdomain_from_url('http://de.example.com/path/?originalSubdomain=de')).to eq(
    "http://example.com/path/?originalSubdomain=de"
  )
end

it 'works properly with nested subdomains' do
  expect(remove_subdomain_from_url('https://nested.subdomain.example.com/')).to eq('https://example.com/')
end

it 'works properly with nested top level domain(suffix)' do
  expect(remove_subdomain_from_url('https://www.de.example.co.uk/path/?originalSubdomain=de')).to eq(
    "https://www.example.co.uk/path/?originalSubdomain=de"
  )
end
```