# Misultin. How can I get subdomain value from request in misultin?

Tags: erlang, misultin

If request is http://subdomain.example.com/blah-blah how can I get **subdomain** value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310547/how-to-get-the-subdomain-value-from-a-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this has nothing to do with misultin. You can simply use regex, for instance:

```
Uri = "http://sub.domain.com",
{match, [_, {Start, Length}]} = re:run(Uri, "(?:http:\/\/)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\..*"),
Subdomain = string:substr(Uri, Start + 1, Length).
```

This will return"sub".

You need to tweak your regex to accomplish exactly what you want to do (i.e. do you need to cover also cases with no subdomain? etc).

Hope this helps,

r.

Comment: I'm playing with _misultin_rest_utf8_ example and in **handle_http(Req)** I getting subdomain this way: `[H|_T] = Req:get(headers), Host = element(2, H)`. Then parsing Host using `re:split(Host, "[.]", [])`. Can I do this in this way?

Comment: yes, that's another way of doing it. otherwise, instead of the split you can use the example i've provided above if you're sure there's a subdomain. otherwise, you need to have a slightly different regex such as "(?:http:\/\/)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\.?.*"