# Url model name in multisite app Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm building a multisite app in Rails for a customer. The functionality is to create new websites and administer them.

I've already set subdomains for each website. Ex.

```
site1.example.com 
site2.example.com
```

Each website has pages which we can create, edit and destroy. Example:

```
site1.example.com/pages/1
```

The problem is that the websites have some pages that have the same name like "Contact".
So I want that in the url shows the name of the page. Example:

```
site1.example.com/contact
site2.example.com/contact
```

No matter if it is:

```
site1.example.com/pages/contact
```

The def_param is not fine because it shows the id of the page before the name.
Friendly_id gem has the slug feature, but we have 2 Pages with the same name. And it puts a number after the name. Example:

```
site1.example.com/pages/contact
site2.example.com/pages/contact--2
```

Any ideas on how to structure this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

validates_uniqueness_of can do so with in a scope paramater.

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :url, :scope => :site_id
end
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of

And of course the controller would look for the page based on the subdomain, so the routes would look pretty normal.

And just in case here is how you get the subdomain

```
request.subdomain
```

[How to get the subdomain value from a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310547/how-to-get-the-subdomain-value-from-a-url)