# Can I make Rails / WEBrick recognize entries in /etc/hosts as subdomains (instead of domains)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain, webrick

I'm trying to use subdomains locally for a Rails app so I added the following line to my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
# add 'test' subdomain for localhost
127.0.0.1 test.localhost
```

Now I can point my browser to `test.localhost:3000` and it hits my Rails app.

However, Rails or WEBrick interprets the whole darn thang as the domain:

```
# logging in the controller
logger.debug("domain: '#{request.domain}', subdomain: '#{request.subdomain}'")

# output in the console
domain: 'test.localhost', subdomain: ''
```

**Is there an easy way to get WEBrick Rails to interpret `test` as the subdomain?**

Thanks!

## Update

I ended up making a `before_action` as a workaround.

```
def set_domain_and_subdomain
  @domain = request.domain
  @subdomain = request.subdomain

  # HACK: force /etc/hosts subdomains
  if Rails.env.development?
    if m = request.domain.match(/([^\.]+).localhost/)
      @subdomain = m[1]
      @domain = 'localhost'
    end
  end
end
```

But I'm still curious if there's a way to do this universally on my computer (i.e. in `/etc/hosts or something)

Comment: I'm aware of services like lvh.me but I don't know how to make it share the same session as localhost so it forces me to facebook auth into the Rails app each time :(

Answer (score 6):

Pretty late to find this post, but for posterity: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12438

Setting the top level domain length (TLD) allowed `request.subdomain` to target the subdomain as you'd expect.

I put `config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 0` into `config/environments/development.rb` and everything worked swimmingly.

*Remember to restart your server*