# Rails 4 custom path helper

Tags: ruby, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, subdomain, helper

I would like to customize my path helpers in Rails 4.

I have a Site5 website (which uses Apache server) with multiple subdomains.  I have rewrite rules in my `.htaccess` file which adds the folder name to the url.  For example

```
cs1337.mysite.com/login
```

is rewritten to

```
cs1337.mysite.com/cs1337/login
```

In routes.rb, I have added a scope in routes.rb:

```
scope '/cs1337' do
  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new', as: :login
  # etc.
end
```

which gives me the correct routing.  Everything works, but the annoying thing is that all my path helpers have the '/cs1337' prefix, which is unnecessary since the `.htaccess` rewrite rules add it back in.  For example,

```
login_path # => /cs1337/login
```

when only

```
login_path # => /login
```

is necessary.

I would like to override all of the path helpers to strip off the prefix, using something like

```
def <override all path helpers> 
  path = super
  path.gsub(%r{^/cs1337}, '')
end
```

I know the path helpers are dynamically generated, but I can't figure out where start ... I can't even find what module the path helpers are generated in.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, as far as I can tell.

I couldn't find anything that lets you have the route Rails intercepts be different from the path that the helpers give you. I don't think Rails plays well with .htaccess rewrites.

Do you need the folder name to be in the path? If not, I would remove the `scope '/cs1337' do` and use something like [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310547/how-to-get-the-subdomain-value-from-a-url) to do domain-specific routes.

If you need it there, I would recommend being okay with the end user seeing "cs1337.mysite.com/cs1337/path".

Comment: DoubleFelix,

Yes, I do need the folder name in the path.  I have to use a symbolic link in my `public_html` directory, to link to the base folder for my rails application.

Comment: Sorry to say, but I think your setup is asking for trouble. Your routing situation is really complicated, to a degree I don't think rails can compensate for.