# Dynamic Routes Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a site that gives each user their own subdomain ie cmcollin41.website.com. Each user can also create their own pages for their subdomain site. Because I allow each user to create their own pages I need to create dynamic routes for those pages. I have looked through all of the other questions on SO and I haven't been able to find an answer that helps me solve this problem.

I currently have most of this working from following this blog post: http://codeconnoisseur.org/ramblings/creating-dynamic-routes-at-runtime-in-rails-4.

My main problem is that I set each user based off of the subdomain and I need to access the request.subdomain somewhere (either in routes.rb or the model or even the lib folder) so that I can iterate thru the subdomain user's pages to create the routes.

here is my code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :pages

def self.load
  Walkaboutio::Application.routes.draw do
    #This doesn't work. I know you can't access the request in the model. 
    #I've been trying for a while to try and figure out how and where to set
    #the user via the request.subdomain so I can create the route for each of 
    #the users pages.
    @account = User.find_by(subdomain: request.subdomain)
    @account.pages.all.each do |pg|
      get "/#{pg.name}", to: "pages#pages", defaults: { id: pg.id }
    end
  end
end

end


class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

protect_from_forgery with: :exception

before_action :set_account

private

  def set_account
    @account ||= User.find_by(subdomain: request.subdomain)
  end

  helper_method :set_account

end


class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def pages
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    @bio = @account.bio
  end

end

routes.rb

class SubdomainConstraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != 'www'
  end
end


Rails.application.routes.draw do

  constraints SubdomainConstraint do 
    root to: 'pages#show', as: :portfolio
    #This is where I load the routes
    User.load
    get '/users/:id/setup', to: 'users#setup', as: :setup
    resources :analytics
    resources :calendars
    resources :events
    resources :users
  end

  root to: 'pages#index', as: :marketing

  get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get '/auth/failure', to: 'sessions#auth_fail'
  get '/sign_out', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: :sign_out

  get 'contact', to: 'events#new', as: 'contact'
  post 'contact', to: 'events#create'

end
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: This link should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310547/how-to-get-the-subdomain-value-from-a-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One downfall of using data-driven route generation in a multi-tenanted app is that routes defined in the app are, for all intent and purposes, global to entire app.

What I'd do in this situation though, is let all routes be built, but in the controller constrain the query to page.id AND account.id and return "not found" or whatever you need to do in this situation. Something like this:

In your pages controller, take advantage of the @account already being set when you issue your set_page:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_page, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  private 

  def set_page
    unless @page = Page.where(account_id: @acount.id, id: params[:id]).first
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    end
  end

end
```